# After 30min inactivity initiall lag on IE due to window.onfocus

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, erp, onfocus, attachedbehaviors

first post here. I have always found good answers on this site but this is the first time that I could not help myself after extensive research on my very specific problem. I attached a function to "onfocus" of the window/tab which calculates what color and other specific variables are shown on an Statuslight I had to implement in the ERPs own Navigational bar. Therefore on every focus it asks if the Information has changed and if it did, it reloads the page. Everything works fine but after about 30 minutes of inactivity in IE(The company only works with IE so I do not have to keep cross browser compability in mind)...after 30min of inactivity it "lags" ca.5 seconds when the window is focused again.(by lag I mean it simply stops doing anything, not tab change, nothing) I think it might be something about a timeout with the application server or something like that but I just don't have enough insight for this. Hope you guys can help me with this. 
Here is the relevant Javascript code:

```
 function addAnpStatusLight() {
  if ((window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("dlg") < 0) && (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("tab.asp") < 0)) {
  //Element initialisieren
  var lAmpelB = document.createElement("img");
  lAmpelB.id = "AnpStatusLight";
  lAmpelB.title = "Browser Terminal";
  lAmpelB.src = absoluteUrl("~/Style/system/blank.gif");
  lAmpelB.onclick = function () {
    window.open(location.href.split("/").slice(0, 4).join("/") + "/time/BrowserTerminal.aspx?_nonav=1");
  }

  var Ampelcolor;
  var BAuftrag = "";
  var Position = "";
  var PositionN = "";
  var Projekt = "";
  var ProjektN = "";

  AmpelColor = fw.getAmpelC();
  currentAmpel = AmpelColor;  //für neuladen bei umstempeln benötigt
  if (AmpelColor.indexOf(",") != -1) {
    var ArAm = AmpelColor.split(",");
    if (ArAm.length == 6) {
      AmpelColor = ArAm.slice(0, 1);
      BAuftrag = ArAm.slice(1, 2);
      Position = ArAm.slice(2, 3);
      PositionN = ArAm.slice(3, 4);
      Projekt = ArAm.slice(4, 5);
      ProjektN = ArAm.slice(5, 6);
      lAmpelB.title = "Projekt: " + Projekt + ", " + ProjektN + "\nBAuftrag: " + BAuftrag + "\nPosition: " + Position + ", " + PositionN;
    } else if (ArAm.length == 4) {
      AmpelColor = ArAm.slice(0, 1);
      BAuftrag = ArAm.slice(1, 2);
      Position = ArAm.slice(2, 3);
      PositionN = ArAm.slice(3, 4);
      lAmpelB.title = "BAuftrag: " + BAuftrag + "\nPosition: " + Position + ", " + PositionN;
    }
  }
  //Farbe setzen
  switch (AmpelColor){
  case "G":
    fw.addClass(lAmpelB, "Green");
    break;
  case "Y":
    fw.addClass(lAmpelB, "Yellow");
    break;
  case "R":
    fw.addClass(lAmpelB, "Red");
    break;
  }
  //Element anfügen
  if (AmpelColor != "NC" && AmpelColor != null) {
    this.element.appendChild(lAmpelB);
  }
 }
}
  window.attachEvent("onfocus", updateAmpel); //bis IE 10



  //lädt die Seite neu falls umgestempelt wurde, an onfocus angehängt
  function updateAmpel() {
    if (currentAmpel != getCurrentAmpel()) {
      var search = window.location.search;
      if (search != "" && search != null) {
        var queryHash = getQueryStringAsHash(search);
        window.location.href = appendQueryHashToUrl(window.location.pathname, queryHash);
      } else {
        window.location.href  = window.location.href
      }
    }
  }

  //berechnet den Ampelstring neu und gibt ihn zurück
  function getCurrentAmpel() {
    var ret;
    ret = fw.getAmpelC();
    return ret;
  }
```

Hope this is enough information to understand my problem. If there are further questions please feel free.

Comment: I'm not seeing a call to an application server in this code.  What does getAmpelC do?

Comment: it calls the method getAmpelC in the file fw.js which houses the actuall call to the server. It goes through several files before it actually reaches the appserver. That's the given architecture I have to work with in the ERP

Comment: I would break out the browser developer tools "network" tab, or Fiddler, and see how long calls to the app server are taking.

Comment: thanks. I will try that